# SUDO I/O logs and TSID

Tags: sudo, logs

I trying to understand the details of sudo session logs, specifically about TSID.

I have a few questions:

1. What does TSID stand for?
2. It is a 6 character sequence which forms the directory structure - 0001A1: what does each pair of 2 characters signify?
3. Any other content related to understanding TSID would be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Background

TSID is described in the `sudoreplay` man page as follows:

> The ID should either be a six character sequence of digits and upper case letters, e.g. 0100A5, or a pattern matching the iolog_file option in the sudoers file. When a command is run via sudo with log_output enabled in the sudoers file, a TSID=ID string is logged via syslog or to the sudo log file. The ID may also be determined using sudoreplay's list mode.

You can use `sudoreplay -l` to list available sessions, to replay one, you'd run a command like this: `sudoreplay <tsid>`.

#### Sample output

I found sample output in a AU Q&A titled: [How to make sudoreplay work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/446079/how-to-make-sudoreplay-work/496337#496337):

```
$ sudo sudoreplay -l
Nov 28 11:48:35 2014 : chrthomp : TTY=/dev/pts/1 ; CWD=/home/chrthomp/DJS/2014/Nov ; USER=root ; TSID=000001 ; COMMAND=/bin/su -

$ sudo sudoreplay 000001
```

#### Further research

If you look through the [`sudoers` man page](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoers.man.html) it explains what the `TSID=` is:

> Input is logged to the directory specified by the iolog_dir option (/var/log/sudo-io by default) using a unique session ID that is included in the normal sudo log line, prefixed with “TSID=”. The iolog_file option may be used to control the format of the session ID.

**NOTE:** A similar paragraph is mentioned on both the `log_input` and `log_output` definitions.

If you read further through the `sudoers` man page you'll discover that `TSID=` is also called `logid`:

```
date hostname progname: username : TTY=ttyname ; PWD=cwd ; \
USER=runasuser ; GROUP=runasgroup ; TSID=logid ; \
ENV=env_vars COMMAND=command
```

Which leads to this:

> logid - 
>   An I/O log identifier that can be used to replay the command's output. This is only present when the log_input or log_output option is enabled.

#### Initial thoughts...

Most of the examples I've found show `TSID=` as either a sequence of numbers (000001) or as a sequence of numbers and letters (000AE1). Curiously I've always seen it with specific letters, mainly A-F, which would lead me to believe that it is either just a increasing integer or hex.

In either case it doesn't appear to be a "smart numbering system" of any consequence.

#### Look to the source code

In `grep`'ing through the sudo code repo there's a [NEWS file](https://github.com/millert/sudo/blob/master/NEWS#L1990) that states the following:

> - The sudoers policy now stores the TSID field in the logs
>     even when the "iolog_file" sudoers option is defined to a value
>     other than %{sessid}.  Previously, the TSID field was only
>     included in the log file when the "iolog_file" option was set
>     to its default value.

If you're curious the source to the `TSID=` is located in the [logging.c](https://github.com/millert/sudo/blob/master/plugins/sudoers/logging.c#L875) file.

#### References

- https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.13/sudoreplay.man.html
- https://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/security-sudo.html

Comment: Sure thing, hopefully it helps out. Please mark as accepted if you're all set.

Answer (score 0):

TSID = TypeScript IDentifier

To be related to the "script" command :
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/script.1.html

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Your answer is rather compact and to a large degree relies on the externally linked man page, which is discoured as external links or the content they point at may change. Please consider editing your post to include more explanation, so that a non-expert can more easily extract the answers to the OPs original 3 questions.